# Google sign in error, Authorization Error Error 400: invalid_request

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have a vue app that use google oauth2 client for user login. My application is hosted on the URI suppose `testing.abc.com`. On the oauth concent screen, Authorized domain is `abc.com`. I have created oauth 2.0 client with Authorized JavaScript origins `https://testing.abc.com` and Authorized redirect URIs `https://testing.abc.com`.

When I try to login to app, I get error stating:
Authorization Error[image]

Here is the sample of the vue code.

```
 window.gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID, plugin_name: 'streamy' })
    .then(function () {
// vue code
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Did you add your domain to authorized javascript origins?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes. I have added domain to authorized javascript origins.

Comment: Google does not like the value you entered for the Redirect URI. Is the redirect a valid https URI for a domain name or http for localhost?

Comment: @JohnHanley I am sorry for putting on incomplete information. Both of the javascript origin and redirect uri have valid domain name with https enabled.

Comment: You might be wasting your time here, as the library in question had already been deprecated. Better move to the suggested replacement already: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web

Comment: Hello @MartinZeitler, Thank You. I will consult with the dev team regarding this.